# How to set a scroll offset in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I need to set an offset in the listview.  I've achieved it initially by using ScrollBy(X, Y), but as soon as I touch the list view it snaps back to zero (my offset in negative).

How can I maintain this offset?

Comment: What do you mean by offset? That there is an empty space at the top of the `ListView`?

Comment: yeah, I'm actually using a grid view but I want to set an offset so that I can have a header bar overtop, when I scroll I want to scroll out the header bar, whilst being able to see more of the gridview content.  But when I scroll down at any position I want to scroll the header bar back in.  The same effect as on twitter's app.  But I can't do this without setting some kind of offset.  I'm trying to play around with intercepting the touch event instead at the moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an empty space at the top of the `ListView` I would do it with a padding.

Add this to your `ListView` in the layout xml

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingTop="25dp"
```

You can also do it programmatically but doing it in xml should always be preferable if possible:

```
float paddingTopInDp = 25.0f;

Resources resources = getResources();
float paddingTopInPixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, paddingTopInDp, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
listView.setClipToPadding(false);
listView.setPadding(0, (int)(paddingTopInPixels + 0.5f), 0, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, given that I would have to adjust the padding on scroll, that would cause a re-layout, which would be very inefficient.  Maybe you have misunderstood what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: No I understand what you mean, I built something very similar.You don't actually have to change the padding. You have to adjust your overlay according to the scrolOffset.

Comment: If the listview is padded, then the content will never fill the screen when the header hides

Comment: That is not true. That's why you set `android:clipToPadding="false"`. If you set this to false than the content will also use the padding.

Comment: Oh now I remember why I couldn't use that method, when I pull down on the list twitter style - say half way through the list, the header would pull down and cover the content, in twitter the list view content moves with it

Comment: Yes put that has nothing to with a padding. I built something exactly like that 2 days ago. You just have to scroll the `ListView` down while the header moves down.

Comment: You can use this method to do this: `listView.scrollListBy(...);`. With this you have to scroll the `ListView` by just as much as the header is tall in pixels. If you animate that it looks very good. Of course you can also do it the other way around. React to the `ListView` scrolling and move the header view down by that much. Depends on what exactly you want.